# Store an value in iOS app which is provided by the user on daily basis?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to store a value of Yes or No locally on the device, day to day. I am not sure how to accomplish that or even where to get started, so I did not try anything in particular yet. Below is the code I use to prompt for the user's input.

```
  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(animated)




// if user didnt yet provided value and time is after 6 pm then only alert will occur

let dateNow = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let hour = calendar.component(NSCalendarUnit.Hour, fromDate: dateNow)

if Score == 0 && hour >= 18  && hour <= 21{



    if !isAlertShown   {
        isAlertShown = true
        let Alert1 = UIAlertController(title: "Meal check", message: "Had Your lunch Today", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let YesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
            UIAlertAction in self.increaseScore()
            self.ScoreView.text = "\(self.Score)"
        }
        let NoAction = UIAlertAction(title: "NO", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) {
            UIAlertAction in self.discreaseScore()
            self.ScoreView.text = "\(self.Score)"
        }

        Alert1.addAction(YesAction)
        Alert1.addAction(NoAction)

        self.presentViewController(Alert1, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }

    // setting if user provided value than cancel the notification and alert for today

    if Score == 1   {



    }


}
```

Comment: consider using Core Data. It's like a DB tool

Comment: The best solution is to use database. CoreData can be a bit too complicated for simple tasks, check out the [realm.io](https://realm.io) it's great

Comment: thanks @JulianE.   lets see what are those  :)

Comment: thanks @ArmandsL. lets see what are those :)

Comment: NSUserDefaults / iCloud Key-Value Storage should suffice for storing a few numbers / dates / strings and it's really easy to set up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a few tutorials you may want to take a look at. Each tutorial is taking a different approach to storing data, both locally and remotely.

1. **Core Data**. This in my opinion is your safest bet. While it may be heard to set up it'll be reliable and you can store data locally. This will give you a database where you can write a key data and yes/no and the write data to those. [Here's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial) a great tutorial from Raywenderlich. [Core Data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial)
2. **Parse**. Your second best bet would be parse. Here you store all your data in a remote database, however this amazing new feature introduced a few months back called *Local Datastore* allows you to also store data locally. Here you simply upload everything to the server and call `.pinInBackground()` on your object. [Here](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/swift/existing) is a great tutorial to get you set up with parse, and [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#local-datastore) is a great guide to get going with local Datastore. [Parse](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/swift/existing) and [Local Datastore](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#local-datastore).
3. **CloudKit.** Lastly, you can use Apple's own version of Parse called CloudKit(based on iCloud). To get set up and running with
   iCloud for developers follow this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83116/beginning-cloudkit-tutorial). This integrates well
   with Core Data, then creating the perfect alternative for Parse.

If you'd ask me, personally I'd go with option B, Parse. But you can also use 1 and 3 to create the exact same alternative, probably more secure as it's all on Apple's own tech.

Hope that helps, Julian.

Comment: hey @julianE. thanks a lot for your effort,  i'll go for whichever is best for my requirement